# Basis formation avoiding vector in certain direction

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose we have two independent vectors $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a set of independent vectors $A=\{w,e_{1},\dots,e_{m}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $v\notin\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}w+\mathcal{L}(\{e_{1},\dots,e_{m}\})$. Is it always possible to complete $A$ to a basis $B=\{w,e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ such that $v\notin\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}w+\mathcal{L}(\{e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\})$? How?

Comment: Either $v = rw + \Sigma r_i w_i$ where $r < 0$ and any completion suffices, or $v$ is independent from $A$ so we add $v + w$ and complete to a basis.

Comment: @interregno Thanks a lot! Post it as an answer so I can give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented,

Since bases by definition can only express elements in one manner, we can use this to give a simple proof.

Either $v$ is independent from $A$ or $v = rw + \Sigma r_i w_i$ with $r < 0$. In the former case $v + w$ is independent so we can take a completion of $A \cup \{ v + w \}$ since the only expression of $v$ is $(v + w) - w$. In the latter case we already have a single possible expression of $v$ with $r < 0$ for the coefficient of $w$.